# Django - Image not supporting while DEBUG = False

Tags: python, django, debugging

In my Django project some of dynamic image files is not served when I change the DEBUG mode into False, other static files are working properly the issue that I faced only in the case of some images. For example if I have 20 products contain 20 images maybe 5 or 6 will not show rest of them have issues.

How can I solve the issue in a production time I can't make DEBUG in True mode, for static serving I have used WhiteNoise module.

Comment: Here's some things for you to check: What are the HTML img src URLs for the ones that work compared to the ones that don't?  Are their srcs created differently in the template? Does your STATIC_ROOT have all the files you expect it to, or did you forget to `manage.py collectstatic` recently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.